# how do i avoid jerky or sudden animation on unhovering the div which is scaling on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to add animation on both hover and unhover state but that jumps the `<div/>` to its original state and then follows the animation.

What can be done to have a fluid animation on hovering and unhovering the `<div/>`?

Any kind of JavaScript and CSS is acceptable, but please avoid GSAP libraries as I am not familiar with them.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  transition: .45s;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 70vw;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  scale: .7;
  animation: shrink .45s ease-in-out 1 forwards;
}

.container:hover {
  scale: 1;
  animation: strech 1.5s ease-in-out 1;
}

@keyframes strech {
  0% {
    scale: .7;
  }
  20% {
    scale: 1;
  }
  40% {
    scale: .9;
  }
  60% {
    scale: 1;
  }
  80% {
    scale: .95;
  }
  100% {
    scale: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes shrink {
  20% {
    scale: .9;
  }
  100% {
    scale: .7;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So, you want the div to before hovering to animate itself and then back normal, then you want on hover to animate itself then back to normal?

Answer (score 0):

Well , after posting the question , i myself came up with a mind-blowing solution which uses variable property .

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}


body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}


.container {
    transition: .45s;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 60vh;
    width: 70vw;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    scale: .7;
    animation: shrink .45s ease-in-out 1 forwards;
}

.container:hover {
    animation: strech 1.5s ease-in-out 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes strech {
    0% {
        scale: .7;
        --val: .7;
    }

    20% {
        scale: 1;
        --val: 1;
    }

    40% {
        scale: .9;
        --val: .9;
    }

    60% {
        scale: 1;
        --val: 1;
    }

    80% {
        scale: .95;
        --val: .95;
    }

    100% {
        scale: 1;
        --val: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes shrink {
    0% {
        scale: var(--val);
    }

    100% {
        scale: .7;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container 1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The reason it snaps back is because of the scale property on container:

```
.container {
    scale: .7;
}
```

When the container reverts back to its default (unhovered) state, it goes to .7 immediately and then plays the animation. If you remove this line then I think you will get the result you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You mispelled the word stretch and you don't need the keyframes shrink.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
 *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container{
    transition:.7s;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 60vh;
    width: 70vw;
    background-color: rgb(42, 116, 228);
    scale: .7;
    animation: shrink .5s 1s;
    }

.container:hover{
    scale: 1;
    animation: stretch 1.5s ease-in-out 1;
}

@keyframes strech {
    0%{
        scale: .7;
    }
    20%{
        scale: 1;
    }
  
    80%{
        scale: .95;
    }
    100%{
        scale:1;
    }
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i used the same spelling in both areas so it does not make any sense .

Answer (score 0):

I'm in no way an expert and really only have surface level knowledge of CSS animations so please take this as a suggestion at best.

What if, for the :hover, you set a transform instead of animation? Something like this:

```
.container {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: transform 1.5s ease-in;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.container:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}

.container:not(:hover) {
  transition: transform 0.45s ease-out;
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

This avoids having to use animation. Tested here: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-microservice-zcwq85?file=/index.html). Obviously adjust the height and width to your needs, I just set it to that to fit the small output. This appeared pretty smooth to me, but not sure if it fits your needs.

Comment: Well , you solution solves the problem but it takes that bounce effect which can be accomplished by only animation iterations .

Comment: Oh sorry about that! I didn't realize it had a bounce effect.